# Rails 4 has_many through: update join model from parent model edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, join

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

I mainly use the `Administration` join model to define a `role` for each `user` in each `calendar`.

So, when a `user` creates a `calendar`, or when a user joins a calendar, a new row is created in the `Administration` model, with the `user_id`, the `calendar_id` and the associated `role`.

All of this has been taken care of.

I also know how to delete a `user` or delete a `calendar`, which automatically deletes all the corresponding administrations thanks to the `dependent: :destroy` option added in both models.

Now, what I am interested in is how I can update the `role` of a `user` for a given `calendar`, in this particular calendar `edit` view.

Note: in this particular situation, a `user`'s `role` is either set to **Editor** or **Viewer**, and can only be updated to the other option.

So far, I have built this table to display the list of the `users` who `belong_to` the `calendar`:

```
<table id="manage_users">

  <tr>
    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> NAME</th>
    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" aria-hidden="true"></span> ROLE</th>
    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> JOINED</th>
    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> OPTIONS</th>
  </tr>

  <% @calendar.users.each do |user| %>

    <tr>
      <% if user.id == current_user.id %>
        <td>You</td>
        <td><%= user.administrations.find_by_calendar_id(@calendar.id).role %></td>
        <td><%= user.administrations.find_by_calendar_id(@calendar.id).created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %>
        </td>
      <% else %>
        <td><%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %></td>
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> <%= user.administrations.find_by_calendar_id(@calendar.id).role %>
        </td>
        <td><%= user.administrations.find_by_calendar_id(@calendar.id).created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %>
        </td>
        <% unless user.id == user.administrations.find_by_calendar_id(@calendar.id).role %>
          <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit Role</td>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tr>

  <% end %>

</table>
```

Where I am struggling now is how to implement the edit role feature.

Should I have insert a kind of "inline form" with two radio buttons — one for **Editor** and the other for **Viewer** — with the current role checked by default?

Or should I go with the `remote: true` route with a JS alert?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not combine the two?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I actually know how to perform a `delete` with `remote: true` — I have this already elsewhere in my app: `<%= link_to 'x', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>` — but I am not sure how I can do the same with radio buttons and an `update` method. Any pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Get a method to handle this:

`user.rb`

```
def update_role(role)
  self.update_attributes(:role, role)
end
```

2) Get a controller action to handle this:

`users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController << ApplicationController
  def update_role
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_role(params[:role)
  end
end
```

3) get a route to your controller action

`route.rb`

```
get "user/role/update" => "user#update_role"
```

4) point your radio_buttons' form to this controller action

```
<%= form_tag (url: "user/role/update" id: user.id), remote: true do %>
```

and put the radio button for `role` in this form, each with the separate types of roles there are.

***NOTE***: *Since you are already familiar with the workings of most of this,much details are not given, Just some pointers on how you might approach this.*

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Makes sense. Just one question. With this approach, is the form displayed in my `Calendars#Edit` view or in a new `Users#update_role` view?

Comment: Anywhere you need it bro. But you don't need to create a new `update_role` view just for this, unless if you want to create it as a partial. So, I'll say: the `calendars#edit` view.

Comment: Ok. I just got confused by the route. Sur thing, thanks a lot, very helpful answer.

Comment: Oh, the route is just to lead any request directly to that action in your controller. It does not necessarily mean that the request should come from the associated view or something like that.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this additional detail. I had only used routes to map actions and views together so far, did not know you could use them otherwise. Thanks again, your help is highly appreciated here.